Running a dc motor with limited current
I am trying to understand something about the motor I want to use for my robot and I am hoping for your help.
I have two DC motors to run a differential drive robot. Each of the motors has the specs as following:
Voltage-rpm     : 12V - 100rpm
No-load current : 300mA
Stall current   : 5A
Stall torque    : 29 kg.cm
Im using l298N motor driver which can supply about 2A current for each motor.
My question is whether it is safe to use this motors with L298N motor driver?
I probably won’t need as much torque as the stall torque, so would I get about a bit less than the half of stall torque when I supply each motor with 2A current coming from my L298N?(since current and torque are proportional and supplying 2A which is less than half the stall current of 5A would give me the corresponding torque?)
I just bought this motors, if they are not the right choice, I would like to return them. So I hope for your answers and appreciate any help.
Thanks.
The product name of the motor is: pololu PL-4847

Like the motor driver, it would be helpful to provide a detailed product name for the motor.
